# Why overloaded operator << works sometimes but other times doesn't

Tags: c++, overloading

I don't know why `cout << da << '\n'` works fine,but `std::cout << next_Monday(da) << '\n'` went wrong. Why the direct `Date` object can output, but the return `Date` can't.
Why overloaded `operator <<` works sometimes but other times doesn't.
here is my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Date {
    unsigned day_: 5;
    unsigned month_ : 4;
    int year_: 15;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Date& b)
{
    out << b.month_ << '/' << b.day_ << '/' << b.year_;
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,Date& b);
Date next_Monday(Date const &d);

int main()
{
    Date da;
    std::cin >> da;
    std::cout << da << '\n';
    std::cout << next_Monday(da) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

this is what clang said: (I use g++ to invoke)

`excercise19DateManipulate.cpp:114:18: error: invalid operands to binary
    expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Date')
    std::cout<< next_Monday(da) <<'\n'; 
    ~~~~~~~~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you can't bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference. Change the operator to take a `const` reference:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Date& b)
```

Comment: Oh!!! My god..I'm so stupid..I didn't notice that was a classic temporary !!!and I try to reference it without a const.. Thanks for answering my first question!

Comment: @W.B. It would work for rvalues, so you'd need two overloads.

Comment: @HRLTY What I posted works for rvalues. That is the point of the answer.

Answer (score -2):

You never defined the "next_Monday()" function as far as I can see, you only declared it.

Comment: That's not the error the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Definitely not a problem